# Counting words and white spaces in python from a text file

Tags: python

So I have this code that reads in a text file, grabs the words, then gets the frequency of each letter. But right now it's not taking into account spaces. Is there a way to modify the following to count for spaces as well. so i'd like `' '` to be a word if that makes sense. I guess i'd also like to factor in new lines as well so `\n`

```
word_list = []

file = open(file_name, 'rU')

for line in file:
    for word in line.split():
       word_list.append(word);

   *frequency code*
```

Comment: `from collections import Counter; c = Counter(open(file_name, 'rU').read())`?

Comment: The `split` method throws away all the delimiters. If you want to keep track of the delimiters, you have to use something different—the `partition` method, or a regexp, or explicit iteration of the string (maybe using the `find` method rather than going character by character, so it's still as fast as `split`), etc.

Comment: Another option is to rethink this as a [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) problem: if you group all the characters by `c.isspace`, you will get alternating groups of non-space and space characters, which `join` up into exactly what you're defining as words. However, this may be a step more abstract than you're used to thinking, in which case explicit loop around characters or around `find` may be simpler, even if it's more verbose.

Comment: Removing the .split and just looking over line fixed my issue. But the groupby seems cool. I might play around with it.

Comment: @DavidDennis: It's basically just `word_list.extend(''.join(grp) for key, grp in groupby(line, str.isspace))`. Or, if you don't need the list and just want to update a counter, `counter.update(…same genexpr…)`. If that seems a little too opaque, try it as `for key, grp in itertools.groupby(line, str.isspace): counter[''.join(grp)] += 1`.

Comment: Anyway, if you've solved this yourself, you should either write and accept your own answer, or delete your question if you don't think it could help anyone else with a similar issue. (If you're worried about giving credit, you can always just mention Coldspeed or me or whoever in the text of your answer, but you'd still be the one who wrote the working code and the answer.)